# Reactjs can not be styled

Tags: reactjs

Thank you for reading my question. I'm a new ReactJs developer.I encounter problem with using React.createElement. In my way, there is only `<p>` tag is styled with text center with code below:

```
render()

{
    return React.createElement('MDBContainer',null,
            React.createElement('MDBRow',null,
                React.createElement('MDBCol',{md:'6'},
                    React.createElement('form',null,
                        React.createElement('p',{className:'h5 text-center mb-4'},'Sign in'),
                        React.createElement('div',{className:'grey-text'},
                            React.createElement('MDBInput',{icon:'envelope',type:'email',error:'wrong',success:'right', label:'account' },'ddd')
                            // React.createElement('input',{type: 'text', value: this.state.value, onChange: (e) => this.handleChange(e)})
                            ))))
        )
}
```

With the code, I can't style MDBInput tag with input field, div with 'grey-text'. How can i style it as the templates in this link: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/forms/basic/
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hadi Mir: thank for your suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can keep seperate css file to style your component. You can add properties according to the way you wish to style the componen

eg:

**Style.css**

```
.input-tag {
    padding: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

And then, you can import that file in your react component as below.

```
import './Style.css'
```

Then you can use the styling component inside input as below

```
 React.createElement('input',className:'input-tag',type: 'text', value: this.state.value, onChange: (e) => this.handleChange(e)})
```

**Or else**

you just make sure whether you have imported { MDBInput } in your react app.

```
import { MDBInput } from "mdbreact";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But in my code, I really want to know why MDBInput don't be styled although p tag is styled.

Comment: @LeMinh  In p tag you have declare the className. Normally the styles can be added using 'className' property. In the same manner you can use that property inside the MDBInput tag. 
And also make sure whether you have imported ,
    import { MDBInput } from "mdbreact";
in your react file.